# parse json and get attributes with rest controller java

Tags: jhipster

I have this code, the entity is persistable I want to make it non persistable so I parse json file and get name and icon values and display them instead of getting this values from database so that is why I want to change this code

```
/**
 * A Pcomponent.
 */


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "pcomponent")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Pcomponent implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "icon")
        private String icon;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public Pcomponent icon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
            return this;
        }

        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Pcomponent name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }

            Pcomponent pcomponent = (Pcomponent) o;
            if (pcomponent.id == null || id == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return Objects.equals(id, pcomponent.id);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(id);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pcomponent{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", icon='" + icon + "'" +
                ", name='" + name + "'" +
            '}';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Spring Data JPA repository for the Pcomponent entity.
     */

    public interface PcomponentRepository extends 
     JpaRepository<Pcomponent,Long> {

      }




    /**
     * A DTO for the Pcomponent entity.
     */
    public class PcomponentDTO implements Serializable {

        private Long id;

        private String icon;

        private String name;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO = (PcomponentDTO) o;

        if ( ! Objects.equals(id, pcomponentDTO.id)) { 
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PcomponentDTO{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", icon='" + icon + "'" +
            ", name='" + name + "'" +
            '}';
        }
    }


/**
 * Mapper for the entity Pcomponent and its DTO PcomponentDTO.
 */


          @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
        public interface PcomponentMapper {

    PcomponentDTO pcomponentToPcomponentDTO(Pcomponent pcomponent);

    List<PcomponentDTO> pcomponentsToPcomponentDTOs(List<Pcomponent> pcomponents);

    Pcomponent pcomponentDTOToPcomponent(PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO);

    List<Pcomponent> pcomponentDTOsToPcomponents(List<PcomponentDTO> pcomponentDTOs);
    /**
     * generating the fromId for all mappers if the databaseType is sql, as the class has relationship to it might need it, instead of
     * creating a new attribute to know if the entity has any relationship from some other entity
     *
     * @param id id of the entity
     * @return the entity instance
     */

        default Pcomponent pcomponentFromId(Long id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Pcomponent pcomponent = new Pcomponent();
            pcomponent.setId(id);
            return pcomponent;
        }
    }

/**
 * Service Implementation for managing Pcomponent.
 */


       @Service
     @Transactional
     public class PcomponentService {

    private final Logger log = 
       LoggerFactory.getLogger(PcomponentService.class);

    private final PcomponentRepository pcomponentRepository;

    private final PcomponentMapper pcomponentMapper;

    public PcomponentService(PcomponentRepository pcomponentRepository, PcomponentMapper pcomponentMapper) {
        this.pcomponentRepository = pcomponentRepository;
        this.pcomponentMapper = pcomponentMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a pcomponent.
     *
     * @param pcomponentDTO the entity to save
     * @return the persisted entity
     */
    public PcomponentDTO save(PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Pcomponent : {}", pcomponentDTO);
        Pcomponent pcomponent = pcomponentMapper.pcomponentDTOToPcomponent(pcomponentDTO);
        pcomponent = pcomponentRepository.save(pcomponent);
        PcomponentDTO result = pcomponentMapper.pcomponentToPcomponentDTO(pcomponent);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     *  Get all the pcomponents.
     *  
     *  @param pageable the pagination information
     *  @return the list of entities
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<PcomponentDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Pcomponents");
        Page<Pcomponent> result = pcomponentRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return result.map(pcomponent -> pcomponentMapper.pcomponentToPcomponentDTO(pcomponent));
    }

    /**
     *  Get one pcomponent by id.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     *  @return the entity
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public PcomponentDTO findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Pcomponent : {}", id);
        Pcomponent pcomponent = pcomponentRepository.findOne(id);
        PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO = pcomponentMapper.pcomponentToPcomponentDTO(pcomponent);
        return pcomponentDTO;
    }

        /**
         *  Delete the  pcomponent by id.
         *
         *  @param id the id of the entity
         */
        public void delete(Long id) {
            log.debug("Request to delete Pcomponent : {}", id);
            pcomponentRepository.delete(id);
        }
    }







/**
 * REST controller for managing Pcomponent.
 */




       @RestController
       @RequestMapping("/api")
       public class PcomponentResource {

    private final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(PcomponentResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "pcomponent";

    private final PcomponentService pcomponentService;

    public PcomponentResource(PcomponentService pcomponentService) {
        this.pcomponentService = pcomponentService;
    }

    /**
     * POST  /pcomponents : Create a new pcomponent.
     *
     * @param pcomponentDTO the pcomponentDTO to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new pcomponentDTO, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the pcomponent has already an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/pcomponents")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<PcomponentDTO> createPcomponent(@RequestBody PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Pcomponent : {}", pcomponentDTO);
        if (pcomponentDTO.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ENTITY_NAME, "idexists", "A new pcomponent cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
        }
        PcomponentDTO result = pcomponentService.save(pcomponentDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/pcomponents/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * PUT  /pcomponents : Updates an existing pcomponent.
     *
     * @param pcomponentDTO the pcomponentDTO to update
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the updated pcomponentDTO,
     * or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the pcomponentDTO is not valid,
     * or with status 500 (Internal Server Error) if the pcomponentDTO couldnt be updated
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PutMapping("/pcomponents")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<PcomponentDTO> updatePcomponent(@RequestBody PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Pcomponent : {}", pcomponentDTO);
        if (pcomponentDTO.getId() == null) {
            return createPcomponent(pcomponentDTO);
        }
        PcomponentDTO result = pcomponentService.save(pcomponentDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, pcomponentDTO.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * GET  /pcomponents : get all the pcomponents.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of pcomponents in body
     */
    @GetMapping("/pcomponents")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<PcomponentDTO>> getAllPcomponents(@ApiParam Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Pcomponents");
        Page<PcomponentDTO> page = pcomponentService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/pcomponents");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * GET  /pcomponents/:id : get the "id" pcomponent.
     *
     * @param id the id of the pcomponentDTO to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the pcomponentDTO, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/pcomponents/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<PcomponentDTO> getPcomponent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Pcomponent : {}", id);
        PcomponentDTO pcomponentDTO = pcomponentService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(pcomponentDTO));
    }

        /**
         * DELETE  /pcomponents/:id : delete the "id" pcomponent.
         *
         * @param id the id of the pcomponentDTO to delete
         * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK)
         */
        @DeleteMapping("/pcomponents/{id}")
        @Timed
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deletePcomponent(@PathVariable Long id) {
            log.debug("REST request to delete Pcomponent : {}", id);
            pcomponentService.delete(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is it that you're having problems with? Please be more specific.

Comment: But that still is not a specific question. Yes, if you want the object to be read from json file rather than database, one of the things you should do is read these from file and not database. But this is not really a site to help with software design, it works far better with specific questions to which a specific answer can be given.